# Is there an R function for finding the rows that contains a specific element in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, rows

Let's say I have a `4x2` matrix.

```
x<- matrix(seq(1:8), 4)
```

That contains the following elements

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

For this specific example, let's say I want to remove the rows that contain a '2' or an '7' (without having to manually look in the matrix and remove them). How would I do this?

Here's something I came up with but it isn't doing what I want it to. I want it to return the row indices in the matrix that contain either a `2` or a `7`.

```
remove<- which(2 || 7 %in% x)
x<- x[-remove,]
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: `which()` is the correct function, but you need to read a bit more about the indexing syntax.

Comment: `x[-which(...), ]` is dangerous in the event that `which` returns no match. Prefer `x[!(...), ]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x[-which(x == 2 | x == 7, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1],]
```

is the simplest, most efficient way I can think of.

the single '|' checks if each element is 2 or 7 (which '||' won't do). arr.ind gives each position as a pair of coordinates, rather than the default single number. [,1] selects each row which has a 2 or 7.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks @RyanGrannell. BTW, you have good R skills at just 19 years old. where did you learn how to program in R?

Comment: thanks, really glad my answer was helpful. To answer your question, I learned it in my spare time, using the R documentation, Twitter and of course Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Dirk said, `which` is the right function, here is my answer:

```
index <- apply(x, 1, function(a) 2 %in% a || 7 %in% a)
> index
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
x[index, ]
```

Comment: doesn't he want ``x[-index,]

Comment: Initially he wanted to remove them, then he came up to `want it to return the row indices in the matrix that contain either a 2 or a 7.`.

Answer (score 3):

`x[-which(...), ]` is not the right approach... Why? See what happens in case `which` finds no match:

```
x <- matrix(8, nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
x[-which(x == 2 | x == 7, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1],] 
#      [,1] [,2]
```

(it returns nothing, while it should return the whole `x`.)

Instead, indexing with logicals is the safer approach: you can negate the vector of matches without risking the odd behavior shown above. Here is an example:

```
x[!(rowSums(x == 2 | x == 7) > 0), , drop = FALSE]
```

which can also be written in the shorter form:

```
x[!rowSums(x == 2 | x == 7), , drop = FALSE]
```